# Sending SMS from Journey to Subscriber with multiple entries

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, mobileconnect

I have a Journey where the start object is Cases (via Salesforce Data entry) that may have multiple instances of the same Customer at any given time, what I want to do based on the Case record criteria is send SMS messages to the user.

I want to know how I can include related Journey (Case ID) and Contact (First Name) into my SMS? What I'm worried about is that the SMS may use any instance of the Subscriber found in the entry DE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible to do but require some setup:

- You'll need to pass Case:LastModifiedDate to entry data
- You'll need to add a boolean field to your entry data extension that defaults to `False`, let's name it `IsSMSSent`

You can then lookup your entry data in SMS message with LookupOrderedRows() and use it inside SMS. Note - depending on your phone number formatting in SF you may be required to modify `MOBILE_NUMBER` to match it.

```
set @caseData = LookupOrderedRows('EntryDeName', 1, 'Case:LastModifiedDate ASC', 
'Case:Contact:Phone', MOBILE_NUMBER, 
'IsSMSSent', 0)
```

You then also need to change that message flag to mark is as sent:

```
set @updateStatus = UpdateData('EntryDeName', 1, 'Case:ID', @caseID, 'IsSMSSent', 1)
```

This will allow for multiple SMS to be send with different case info, even when multiple cases will be created for same contact at the same time. I encountered similiar issue, you can see detailed description [here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/199776/26268)